# No signature of method: com.foo.D.doSomething() is applicable for argument types: (com.foo.C)

Tags: java, groovy

I'm coming from a Java background and my Groovy skills are still quite minimal...

I have the following in Java:

- Interface `A`
- Class `C` implements `A`
- Class `D` which has a method that accepts instances of `A`: `doSomething(A a)`

And the following Groovy code:

```
import com.foo.A

def c = new C()

assert c instanceof com.foo.A

def d = new D()
d.doSomething(c);    

return true;
```

First, of all the `assert` fails:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: D1_groovyProxy cannot be cast to com.foo.A
```

If I comment out the `assert`, I get

```
No signature of method: com.foo.D.doSomething() is applicable for argument types: (com.foo.C) values: [blah blah]

Possible solutions: doSomething(com.foo.A)
```

I also tried defining:

```
def c = new C() as C
```

... but I still keep getting the `ClassCastException` mentioned above.

I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help, as this has been driving me mental for hours now...

Comment: You can't do `new` on an *interface*. Groovy will fail with *"You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface"*

Comment: @Andreas: Apologies, I made a mistake in my example. I've corrected it. It's not `A`, but `C`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce using GroovyConsole 2.3.10 with script as in question, except fixed imports.

Comment: @Andreas: It seems `A.doSomething(...)` has several `doSomething` methods. One of them has a method like `doSomething(String a, String b, String c...)`. From what I understand the `String c...` is confusing Groovy and it can't figure out which method to really invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Created below sample code using your question in `groovyConsole`. And it works perfectly fine.

```
package com.foo
interface A {
  void doThat()
}

class C implements com.foo.A {
   void doThat() { println "doing that"}
}

class D {
  void doSomething(com.foo.A obj) {      
    println "doing something.."
    obj.doThat()
  }
}

def c = new C()

assert c instanceof com.foo.A

def d = new D()
d.doSomething(c)
```

**Output:**

> doing something..
>   doing that